# What kind of CSS attributes are these?

Tags: css, attributes, custom-attributes

What are these types of attributes called?

```
data-role=
data-theme=
data-position=
data-display=
```

Those specific attributes are coming out of Phonegap but I've seen these in other web frameworks.  Are these custom or part of CSS3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the  [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes):

> HTML5 is designed with extensibility for data that should be in the HTML, but not visible. data-* attributes allow us to store extra information on standard, semantic HTML elements without polluting the class name.
>
> The syntax is easy. Say you have an article and you want to store some extra information that doesn’t have any visual representation. Just use data attributes for that:

```
<article
  id="electriccars"
  data-columns="3"
  data-indexnumber="12314"
  data-parent="cars">
...
</article>
```

Comment: Thanks.  As long as you start with "data-" this attribute will be valid but only in HTML5?

Comment: Valid? Yes. But you'll see it elsewhere for sure.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: You can use it in HTML4. It wouldn't be valid but it would work.

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks again.